# How can I get the enum value of SQL database in PHP

Tags: php, sql, enums

So I'm saving user's ranks into a SQL database as enumerators. I then want to try and check their rank and compare it to a string. If the rank is equal to the string then I want to allow them access. Here is my code so far (Which doesn't work):

```
    $email = stripslashes($email);
    $password = stripslashes($password);
    $email = mysql_real_escape_string($email);
    $password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);
    $sql = "SELECT RANK FROM $table WHERE EMAIL = '$email' and PASSWORD = '$password'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    $count = mysql_num_rows($result);

    if($count == 1){
        if($result == "OWNER") {
            header("location: panel.php");
        } else {
            $message = "Permission denied.";
        }
    } else {
        $message = "Incorrect email or password.";
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

**IMPORTANT NOTICE!**

`mysql_*` functions are deprecated since PHP 5.5.0. It's highly recomended to use [MySQLi](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) instead.

Answering your question, you have to fetch the query result or use `mysql_result()`

**Query**

```
$sql = "SELECT RANK
        FROM $table
        WHERE EMAIL = '$email' and PASSWORD = '$password'
        LIMIT 1";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
```

**Fetch the result:**

```
$rank = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$rank = $rank['RANK'];
```

Or use `mysql_result()` instead:

```
$rank = mysql_result($result);
```

Comment: I know their deprecated but when I tried PDO, I couldn't even get the user to successfully log in...

Answer (score 0):

you have to [mysql_fetch_assoc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) the $result var before you can read the table row. Also I would recmmend you to use mysqli functions. Here, try this instead of yours (without mysqli, and not tested by myself):

```
$email = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($email));
$password = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($password));
$sql = "SELECT `RANK` FROM ".$table." WHERE `EMAIL` = '".$email."' and `PASSWORD` = '".$password."'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

$count = mysql_num_rows($result);

$result = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

if($count == 1){
    if($result == "OWNER") {
        header("location: panel.php");
    } else {
        $message = "Permission denied.";
    }
} else {
    $message = "Incorrect email or password.";
}
```